# SQL Server Select where function very slow .. select where function

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, function, where-clause

I have some views joined up that select from a sharePoint table so I have no control over indexes. it's only 3000 rows so no biggie.  I need to be able to select all rows that have the same department as a particular user. I created a function but if placed in a where clause is too slow. Do I have another option like a join, nested select or stored procedure?

This is very slow:

```
select * 
from apt_files_detailed 
where apt_department = [dbo].[APT_GetDept]('mydomain\jdoe')
```

Yet these are not:

```
select * from apt_files_detailed
```

and

```
select [dbo].[APT_GetDept]('domain\user')
```

I need to be able to select inline inside an ASP.NET page where I don't have code-behind access. Rather not use a stored procedure unless I can select from it directly in the control. Also must pass the user parameter in.

Also, in ASP.NET can I do this:

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [APT_Files_Detailed] where [apt_department] = [dbo].[apt_Getdept](@context)"

WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="LOGON_USER" PropertyName="ParameterValues" Name="context"
```

Just not sure if it should be `(@context)` or `('@context')` .. idk if having syntax issue as the page times out anyways.

Maybe I can use nested select, join or stored procedure in place of the function?

Thanks.

Plan:

```
    select * from apt_files_detailed where apt_department = [dbo].[APT_GetDept]('domain\jdoe')
  |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[nvarchar1])=([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[nvarchar1]), RESIDUAL:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[nvarchar1]=[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[nvarchar1]))
       |--Merge Join(Inner Join, MANY-TO-MANY MERGE:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[int1])=([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_ID]), RESIDUAL:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[int1]=[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_ID]))
       |    |--Sort(ORDER BY:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[int1] ASC))
       |    |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_SiteId], [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_RowOrdinal], [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DirName], [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_LeafName], [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DeleteTransactionId], [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_Level], [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_IsCurrentVersion], [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_CalculatedVersion], [Expr1010]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
       |    |         |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[AllUserData_PK]),  WHERE:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_IsCurrentVersion]=(1) AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_CalculatedVersion]=(0) AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DeleteTransactionId]=0x AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DirName]=N'sites/apt/Process'))
       |    |         |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[AllUserData_Url]), SEEK:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_SiteId]=[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_SiteId] AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DeleteTransactionId]=[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DeleteTransactionId] AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_IsCurrentVersion]=[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_IsCurrentVersion] AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DirName]=[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DirName] AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_LeafName]=[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_LeafName] AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_CalculatedVersion]=[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_CalculatedVersion] AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_Level]=[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_Level] AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_RowOrdinal]=[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_RowOrdinal]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
       |    |--Sort(ORDER BY:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_ID] ASC))
       |         |--Filter(WHERE:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[nvarchar7]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(100),[SharePoint_UM_Custom].[dbo].[APT_GetDept]('domain\jdoe'),0)))
       |              |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[AllUserData_Url]), WHERE:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_IsCurrentVersion]=(1) AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_CalculatedVersion]=(0) AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DeleteTransactionId]=0x AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DirName]=N'sites/apt/Lists/APT'))
       |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1009]=N'domain\'+[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[nvarchar3]))
            |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[AllUserData_Url]), WHERE:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_IsCurrentVersion]=(1) AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_CalculatedVersion]=(0) AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DeleteTransactionId]=0x AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DirName]=N'sites/apt/Lists/Cnum2CaneID'))
  UDF: [SharePoint_UM_Custom].[dbo].[APT_GetDept]
    CREATE FUNCTION APT_GetDept
(
    @user varchar(100)
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Dept varchar(100)
    SET @Dept = (SELECT TOP 1 apt_department FROM apt_faculty WHERE lookup_caneid = @user)
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1008]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(100),[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[nvarchar7],0)))
                 |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join)
                      |--Constant Scan
                      |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))
                           |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[nvarchar1]=[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[nvarchar1]))
                                |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[AllUserData_Url]), WHERE:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_IsCurrentVersion]=(1) AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_CalculatedVersion]=(0) AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DeleteTransactionId]=0x AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DirName]=N'sites/apt/Lists/Cnum2CaneID' AND (N'domain\'+[WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[nvarchar3])=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(100),[@user],0)))
                                |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[AllUserData_Url]), WHERE:([WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_IsCurrentVersion]=(1) AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_CalculatedVersion]=(0) AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DeleteTransactionId]=0x AND [WSS_Content_apt].[dbo].[AllUserData].[tp_DirName]=N'sites/apt/Lists/APT'))
        RETURN @Dept
```

Comment: Do you have an index on apt_department?

Comment: large number of records without indexes can slow down while searching for matches.

Comment: Can you use explain on you query and post the results.

Comment: No indexes,but only 3000 rows. And actually it's a sharePoint List source so don't think I can index.

Comment: here's what I got apt_files_detailed is a view joining 3 selects of sharePoint lists (all in the same table) .. I can't mess with those tables.  GetDept, is a function using a Top and where clause.

Comment: can I select from a stored procedure and seperate the two? think it's calling the function 3000 times.

Comment: Can I use nested select, join or stored procedure in place of the function somehow..